# Is this true they requested for deposit

Tags: reward

The mining pool inform me that I have a reward and they asked to deposit around 5000 USDT so I can collect the rewards is it true [image]

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that is absolutely, without a shadow  of doubt, a scam. If you already deposited money, i'm really sorry. In any case, do not interact with this website any further.